# Can we always off diagonalize matrices with purely imaginary eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Consider a two-by-two matrix $A$ which has real entries with purely imaginary eigenvalues. I am wondering if one can deduce that $A$ under some basis is given by

$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & \lambda \\ -\lambda &0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

**My thoughts:** I think this is probably false  thinking about this as some sort of Jordan block. However, I am finding it very difficult to find a countable example as one needs to show that there doesn't exist a change of basis.

**Context:** This arises out of me thinking about dymanical systems. More precisely, I have seen people use this jump when thinking about centers, however, I am not sure if this is generally true.

Comment: What does "Can be written as" mean? A matrix is ... exactly that matrix. 

Do you mean "is conjugate to"? Or "the transformation represented by multiplication by $M$, expressed with respect to some basis is"? Or "has jordan normal form equal to"?

Comment: Apologies, I have clarified my question.

Comment: Yes, with eigenvalues $a\pm bi$, you can change basis to get $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a\end{bmatrix}$. (Think about multiplication by the complex number.)

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin. Could you clarify what you mean by multiplication by a complex number here? I can see that the given matrix is the matrix representation of a+bi however, I don't see how one proceeds from here.

Comment: If there is a complex vector $v=x+iy$ with $T(v)=(a+bi)v$, then write that out. The fact that $T$ is real tells you $T(x)$ is the real part and $T(y)$ is the imaginary part.

Comment: You're right to be worried about Jordan blocks. The matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ has purely imaginary eigenvalues (under the standard definition of "purely imaginary", as far as I know), but doesn't have this property (for example, because similarity preserves rank or "order of nilpotency"). But if the eigenvalues are *nonzero* and purely imaginary, they must be distinct, and hence the matrix must be diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$, so this behaviour can't happen and in that case Ted's argument is right.